# Convert String to Timestamp in Scala using Java.time

Tags: scala, java-8, java-time

I am trying to convert the below string format to timestamp

`Mon Oct 29 14:33:09 MYT 2018`
to 
`2018-10-29T14:33:09.756Z`

this is my code

```
val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )
print(LocalDateTime.parse(approximateArrivalTimestamp.toString(), format).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toString())
```

and the output is

`2018-10-29T14:33:09Z`

Whats the way that i can get the timestamp up to the granularity of milliseconds like `2018-10-29T14:33:09.756Z`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: if the milliseconds details are missing in the input, then you will get 0's in the conversion..

Answer (score 0):

```
val dateString = "Mon Oct 29 14:33:09 MYT 2018"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )

val date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())

val formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")

date.format(formatter2)
```

For some weird reason you are interpreting this as `LocalDateTime`. I think you should be using `ZonedDateTime` to parse the date and then transform it to your timezone (it will correctly transform the date in your local timezone).

```
val dateString = "Mon Oct 29 14:33:09 MYT 2018"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )

val date = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())

val formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")

date.format(formatter2)
```

And if you want the date to be with a `Z` (Z represents the timezone to be UTC) then you will have to transform it for UTC.

```
val date2 = date.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))

date2.format(formatter2)
// String = 2018-10-29T06:33:09.000Z
```

Comment: hey thanks , I tried as you have given but this is what i get now `2018-10-29T14:27:06.000+08` .

Comment: That is because you are interpreting the date to be in your local timezone which is `+0800` compared to UTC which is represented by `Z`.